discord.py not registering hybrid commands with user install inside of cogs
discord.py doesn't seem to register user install with a hybrid command inside of a cog. Only inside of a guild using a app command and prefixed command.
main.py
import asyncio
import os
import platform
from typing import Final
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
BOT_TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
BOT_PREFIX: Final[str] = os.getenv('BOT_PREFIX')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s')


class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cogs_list = ['cogs.ping']

    async def setup_hook(self):
        # Load all extensions (cogs)
        for extension in self.cogs_list:
            try:
                await self.load_extension(extension)
                logging.info(f'Loaded extension {extension}')
            except commands.ExtensionError as e:
                logging.error(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.', exc_info=True)
        await self.tree.sync()

    async def on_ready(self):
        logging.info(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')

    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send("Command not found.")
        else:
            logging.error(f'Error in command {ctx.command}: {error}')


def main():
    intents: discord.Intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True  # NOQA
    intents.message_content = True  # NOQA

    bot = Client(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents=intents, application_id=1194032001083265104)

    if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

    asyncio.run(bot.start(BOT_TOKEN))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

ping.py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from utils import cogs
from utils.embeds import StyledEmbed


class PingCog(cogs.BaseExtension):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        super().__init__(client)

    @app_commands.user_install()
    @app_commands.allowed_contexts(guilds=True, dms=True, private_channels=True)
    @commands.hybrid_command(name="ping", description="Pong!", with_app_command=True)
    async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Pong! Checks the current client latency."""
        bot_latency = round(self.client.latency * 1000)
        e = StyledEmbed(title="Pong!", description=f"Latency:\n`{bot_latency}ms`")
        await ctx.send(embed=e)


async def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    await client.add_cog(PingCog(client))

I tried a bunch of things, using 2 functions, combining decorators, and probably something but I forgot, but doesn't seem to work inside of dms, other guilds and private channels. it works just fine without the hybrid command

In main.py, you need to load the extension you want to use:
async def start_bot():  
        await client.load_extension('ping')
        await client.start(BOT_TOKEN)

asyncio.run(start_bot())

In ping.py, I don't know what is cogs.BaseExtension that you are using, this is how it worked for me:
from discord.ext import commands

class PingCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

    @commands.hybrid_command(name="ping", description="Pong!", with_app_command=True)
    async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        ...


async def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    await client.add_cog(PingCog(client))

With hybrid commands, you actually don't need to manage the app_commands.
When working with slash commands/tree, is important to sync your slash commands. To do so, I have a command like this:
@client.command(name='refreshslashcommands')
async def refreshslashcommands(ctx):
    await client.tree.sync()
    await ctx.send('Commands refreshed.')

Launch the command, close the Discord client and once restarted you should be able to see the slash command.
